# Compat version of EditTextPreferences ignores xml attributes

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences

I'm using a PreferenceFragmentCompat which inflates the preferences to a different EditTextPreference class than the stock one.

Here's the preference code:

```
  <EditTextPreference
        android:key="description"
        android:title="Description"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:lines="3"
        android:summary=""/>
```

The problems I'm running into are:

- soft keyboard doesn't automatically come up
- text doesn't get selected on focus
- dialog still shows a single-line EditText

What am I missing?

EDIT: the formatting part can be achieved using android:dialogLayout in the preference. However, the keyboard never comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not working with PreferenceCompat et al, but you can use the following code to get the EditText:

```
EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(key_of_preference);
EditText et = etp.getEditText();
```

Now, on the EditText, do what you want, such as setting hint, typeface etc.